# Latitude & Dell TB19 USB-C thunderbolt Nightmare with ubuntu 21

Tags: kernel, usb-device, pci

Internet is already full of Dell WD19TB dock problem... but i didn't found answer for my random crashes on a fresh install, and a fresh dock.

Nothing works well (multi screen, ethernet, etc.) with latest Ubuntu 21, dock Thunderbolt WD19TB using Usb-C and Latitude 7410. Dock is authorized and energy / charge is the only thing that works well.

Even cold/hot plugged i have this information :

```
➜ boltctl                                                
 ○ Dell WD19TB Thunderbolt Dock
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          WD19TB Thunderbolt Dock
   ├─ vendor:        Dell
   ├─ uuid:          0074c1e4-aad2-d400-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ generation:    Thunderbolt 3
   ├─ status:        disconnected
   ├─ authorized:    mar. 04 mai 2021 06:55:21
   ├─ connected:     mar. 04 mai 2021 06:55:21
   └─ stored:        lun. 26 avril 2021 06:47:49
      ├─ policy:     iommu
      └─ key:        no

➜ fwupdmgr get-devices                                   
Latitude 7410
│
├─PC SN730 NVMe WDC 1024GB:
│     Device ID:          6cc1c2d37a98d92020a9c80f9cc15d88a0656184
│     Summary:            NVM Express Solid State Drive
│     Current version:    11150012
│     Vendor:             Sandisk Corp (NVME:0x15B7)
│     GUIDs:              10215a6e-5eb4-5fe4-a3d0-1ff4b3295840
│                         e3a1928f-2cb0-4b92-8526-9368d8c0c2d1
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Supported on remote server
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│   
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Device ID:          baccc6ce3addfafe7012c24cd5f60f2f9d41c832
│ │   Current version:    1.5.2
│ │   Minimum Version:    1.5.2
│ │   Vendor:             Dell Inc. (DMI:Dell Inc.)
│ │   GUIDs:              ae3bd037-2f4a-414c-9f1c-493a454171da
│ │                       230c8b18-8d9b-53ec-838b-6cfc0383493a
│ │                       6edb33d7-4632-503c-a9f1-f057af06d598
│ │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
│ │                       • Updatable
│ │                       • System requires external power source
│ │                       • Supported on remote server
│ │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │ 
│ └─UEFI dbx:
│       Device ID:        362301da643102b9e38477387e2193e57abaa590
│       Summary:          UEFI Revocation Database
│       Current version:  238
│       Minimum Version:  238
│       Vendor:           UEFI:Linux Foundation
│       Install Duration: 1 second
│       GUIDs:            00fe3755-a4d8-5ef7-ba5f-47979fbb3423
│                         4a6cd2cb-8741-5257-9d1f-89a275dacca7
│                         c6682ade-b5ec-57c4-b687-676351208742
│                         f8ba2887-9411-5c36-9cee-88995bb39731
│       Device Flags:     • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│     
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          df945476b677e7a2dab827b25b9807ed655fc132
│     Current version:    222
│     Minimum Version:    222
│     Vendor:             DMI:Dell Inc.
│     GUIDs:              ffd6eef5-4372-4adc-8eeb-3dc0b7338375
│                         fbfd77fb-abcd-56bc-bb4b-27bcd6c22fb4
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          5b1ec19a3f6b7f8du4e7dec250ecbf3ea1be366e
│     Current version:    286588946
│     Minimum Version:    286588946
│     Vendor:             DMI:Dell Inc.
│     GUIDs:              e3a1928f-2cb0-4b92-8526-9368d8c0c2d1
│                         1dc76a3d-4347-5a73-91f2-9fe9fd30e334
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│   
└─USB2.0 Hub:
      Device ID:          b0a78eb71f4eeea7dfxfb114522556ba8ce22074
      Summary:            USB 2.x Hub
      Current version:    30.3
      Vendor:             VIA Labs, Inc. (USB:0x2109)
      Install Duration:   15 seconds
      GUIDs:              1cea77d9-5efe-5499-9d65-228a3cf7160b
                          20054c2d-afa4-5f73-ade0-18dbd6f09fa5
                          ae960a48-da94-5862-94b0-f38f69e4f74d
                          e5211a7f-db4d-5122-8bc3-5ccba6b7f45a
                          2546d7af-3b17-5174-8ff5-e92f441a926f
                          b0a54e37-45da-53f3-98c6-4b33a105d30e
      Device Flags:       • Updatable
                          • Cryptographic hash verification is available
                          • Device stages updates
                          • Device can recover flash failures
```

Basic info :

```
➜ uname -ra
Linux IRED-15-19C0 5.11.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 20:12:43 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

During boot i have this error :

```
xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
xhci_hcd 0000:37:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
pcieport 0000:39:04.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
```

Even when dual screen works at startup (alignment of planet), it's common to observe a crash after some minutes with random TB disconnection.

My cmd line :

```
cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-16-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--budgie--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

**Update :**

I try that, don't work :

- https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9300-and-WD19TB-linux-problem/m-p/7723066/highlight/true#M72030
  Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use any Ubuntu that aren't LTS like the 21.04 you're using, since non LTS Ubuntu are in fact Beta versions (hence the bugs) even if they won't admit it.

This means you should install the latest Ubuntu LTS to have a stable system, which is 20.04.2: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2.0/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso

If you want the latest hardware to be supported, you will need 20.04's Hardware Enablement Stack, which you can just get by installing the `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` package.

Also, never ever update an LTS Ubuntu to a non-LTS one if you don't want issues later. The next LTS is 22.04.

Once you've done it, you may also want to update your BIOS since it already has fixed some issues with the same dock you have:
https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Dell-WD19TB-Dock-Dell-Precision-Mobile-5540-Ubuntu-Linux-18-04/td-p/7375301

You can do that either the classic way (USB key + BIOS file flashing) or with `lsb-release` command.